# How to properly install packages in Aurelia skeleton-typescript-webpack?

Tags: typescript, webpack, aurelia

I'm working on building up a sample application using the Aurelia's skeleton-typescript-webpack sample.

I added moment.js using npm install moment --save

I created a value converter in which I want to use moment:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

export class DateFormatValueConverter {
    toView(value){
        return moment(value).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm A");
    }
}
```

This all looks good in the IDE. However, when I run it, the browser console indicates that "moment is not a function". Looking in the debugger, the moment object doesn't appear to have been loaded properly.

I'm as yet unfamiliar with the inner workings of the various loaders, so I probably missed a step. What *am* I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, it looks like I was doing everything correct...mostly. It appears that Moment's .d.ts file isn't correct. I had to specifically include something like this:

```
this.localMoment = require("moment");
```

After I did that, everything worked just fine.